I cut a carrot with <the> knife perpendicular to it

I cut a carrot with the knife perpendicular to it and then mixed
the resulting carrot rounds with mashed potato.

If I said this sentence to you in a situation where "the knife" had not previously been referred to, would you say the is wrong, or would you assume "the knife" to be my knife?
Thank you.

Not the question here, but the issue of the slicing ambiguity can be solved by reference to axes/directions (along the length) or by resulting shapes (into rounds). Perpendicular to what? Note that mentioning the axis alone isn't enough. Once had an argument over being told to fold towels "three times lengthwise" and guessing wrong at whether this meant creating folds along the length or so as to shorten the length. It meant the latter to my interlocutor.

Thank you, @LukeSawczak. Is there an antonym of "lengthwise"?

Based on my anecdote, one antonym of "lengthwise" is "lengthwise" :) But you can certainly use "widthwise". It's not as common, and might feel ad hoc to some speakers, but is easily understood. (Well, as easily as "lengthwise", anyway.)

Thank you again, @LukeSawczak.

Btw, here's a video with "widthwise" at 1:16. It's not qute clear to me as a native speaker why he chose "widthwise", but it doesn't feel wrong. Looking at that plastic piece from the front, the top and bottom edges seem like the "width", the left and right the "height", and through the opening might be the "length" or "depth" (probably perceiving it as length because of the long piece that runs through it). When he grips it with the pliers, he does so on the left and right, thus clamping/squeezing the width.

Thank you, @LukeSawczak. Is it possible to say "cut a cucumber crosswise"?

Interesting... I might think of it as cutting it into four pieces by cutting a cross on the face, i.e. with a result something like this. But I'd be curious to know what other English speakers say.

It is common to use the definite article when the situation under discussion always, or stereotypically, involves one of the things mentioned.

When painting near the ceiling, hold the brush at an angle.
I was changing the blade on the saw and for a moment couldn't remember whether the nut should be turned clockwise or counter-clockwise.
When we got to our hotel room, I wanted to make a quick cup of coffee as a pick-me-up, but the coffee machine was broken.
We went to the high-school football game on Friday night and sat in the bleachers.
I couldn't find the archeology section so I asked at the desk.

The rule is: don't use the definite article if your listener won't know what you're referring to, and is likely to ask "What desk?" or "What coffee machine?" or "What's this brush you're talking about?"

Many thanks, @TimR.

It's all a very weird way to talk, but not an actual mistake in grammar.
It's weird because you are including details that could easily be inferred from the context.  Of course, you used a knife. Nobody would think you would use a saw or wire to cut carrots.  Of course, the cuts were perpendicular to the long axis of the carrot.  Unless you are talking to an alien that has never seen a carrot before, you don't talk like that.
The use of "the knife" is correct,  because it would either have already been referred to, either explicitly or implicitly. You can answer the question "which knife" using the fact that we know that a knife is used to cut up carrots (not a saw, etc) and so from common knowledge the knife is your knife (the one you use for preparing vegetables).

Thank you, @James K. In my sentence, does "rounds" make "with the knife perpendicular to it" unnecessary?

I would suggest I sliced the carrot. Carrots may also be diced (cut into cubes) or cut into sticks, but slicing implies making parallel cuts across a food item.

Thank you, @KateBunting. I don't know what a "parallel cut" is. Is it a carrot round in my context?

Parallel cuts are cuts made in parallel with one another. Are you familiar with sliced bread? Slicing a carrot, cucumber, banana etc. results in a series of round slices.

(There may be a cross-cultural difference here in the paradigmatic image of cutting a carrot—whether it’s in direction across its length or along it?)

Thank you, @KateBunting. I think I'm familiar with sliced bread to some extent.

Thank you, @PaulTanenbaum. I don't what "in direction along it" means in my context.

It means with the knife pointing in the same direction as the carrot, parallel to it, so that the resulting slices are not disks, but long skinny triangles. And there was a typo: I meant in the direction.

Thanks, @PaulTanenbaum.

@KateBunting I think parallel cuts can be oval. But, your point seems to be that using "sliced" would rule out that possibility in my context.

As I mentioned in an earlier question, in some contexts or cultures a mandoline or similar device might actually be more common than a knife. @Kaguyahime "Slices" is simply a quick way of communicating "make multiple parallel cuts all the way through the object, creating uniform skinny pieces." You can certainly make oval slices; a common recipe-instruction way to communicate this would be "slice the carrot on the diagonal." You could also slice along the long-axis of the carrot, often communicated as "slice the carrot lengthwise" or "along its length."

Cuts can't be oval, but, as Andy says, the resulting slices could be if the knife/cutter was at an angle to the vegetable instead of perpendicular.

Oops. I made a terrible blunder. Cuts are three-dimensional objects, so they can't be oval. Thank you, Andy and Kate.

No, cuts are not "objects"  they are actions.  They are not three dimensional.  The slices are three dimensional, but thin, so can be described as "oval".  "Oval" can mean either a 2d or 3d shape.  Both eggs and ellipses can be called "oval".

But this is all silly talk.  You cut the carrot into rounds.  You don't need to say "perpendicular" or "knife"

Thanks, @JamesK. I didn't know the expression "cut something into rounds". I must say English language education in Japan is execrable. Most Japanese don't even know the word "armpit". It's very hard to learn practical English without living in an English-speaking country.

The Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English defines "oval" as "a shape like a circle, but wider in one direction than the other". Is this definition inaccurate?

It's accurate enough, but eggs are also oval....  "cut into rounds" isn't a fixed expression.  It's just a description: It's a sentence I made up from the meaning of the words "cut" and "round". "cut (the carrot) into pieces that are round".

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

In fact, oval means egg-shaped! By cut I meant 'the opening made by the action of cutting'. The resulting slices are round or oval depending on the angle of the knife.

Thank you, @Kate Bunting. If you cut a cucumber crosswise, what shape are the slices?

Round/circular, according to the normal understanding of cutting a long fruit or vegetable crosswise.
